# How to get frequency calculations categorised by age in r

Tags: r, frequency

I have an experiment where participants had to enter 10 associations for 15 different word prompts. Now I'm interested in getting a frequency count of how many time each association appears for each of the different prompts, but also divided into age groups.

For example, if I have a prompt called `Media`, I would like to have a three columns `freqMedia15-30`, `freqMedia31-45` etc.

I need these columns for each of the prompts. But I don't know if there's a smarter way to do it.

My age groups are `15-30`, `31-45`, `46-60`.

I've managed to get frequency for each prompt by using:

```
Media <- subset(testdata, prompt == "Media")
w = table(Media$typedWord)
t = as.data.frame(w)
names(t)[1] = 'typedWord'

Media <- merge(Media, t, by = "typedWord")`
```

But this doesn't take the age groups into account. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Maybe not exactly how your data is (not sure I get exactly your data structure) but considering you got a column with counts or hits, you can do `aggregate(counts ~ typeWord + ageGroup, data = Media, FUN = sum)` or if you got a "dummy" column with only ones, you can use that instead of `counts`

Comment: @Andrea Dioni did the comment or answer help you? If so, please comment and/or upvote

Answer (score 0):

Considering I understood more or less your data structure, and that you have an eventual column with "hits" or "counts" you can do

```
aggregate(counts ~ typeWord + ageGroup, data = Media, FUN = sum)
```

This works also if you add a "dummy" column `Media$counts = rep(1, nrow(Media))`

Example:

```
> df = data.frame(typeWord = c(rep("bla", 4), rep("tra", 6)), ageGroup = c(rep("10-15", 2), rep("16-21", 4), rep("22-30", 4)), counts = c(1,4,8,2,3,9,5,1,2,1))
> aggregate(counts ~ typeWord + ageGroup, data = df, FUN = sum)
  typeWord ageGroup hits
1      bla    10-15    5
2      bla    16-21   10
3      tra    16-21   12
4      tra    22-30    9
```